# JDK 7 doesn't work with JMF image capture

Tags: jmf, java-7

I tried using the recent JDK release - JDK 1.7.0-ea with one of my java applications that uses JMF to capture facial image, but the motion image gets displayed at the back of the frame - on whatever application opened at the background or on the desktop. I even downloaded the latest JMF but still got the same result. I had to revert to JDK 1.6

I don't know if anyone knows why this is happening.